# Repairing rust damage and dents on my standby car

Tags: metal, sanding, rust-removal, rust-proofing

My standby car has got some nicks and minor small dents. Also there is some rust damage on two of the doors and part of the fender, usually spots where dew drop collects. At some places the rusting seems to be superficial bubble formation (underneath the paintwork), and at some spots the bubbles have spread, ruptured (paint is off it) and seems to have gone deeper.

A neighbor, suggested that I scrape-off the rust, use dry sand-paper and use any sharp object to rupture the bubbles that are still under paint, and then I should spray some WD-40. After letting the place dry and wiping it off with dry cloth, I should fill the spots with 'metal paste / putty' using plaster knife. The metal paste apparently dries quite quickly, and before it is completely dry, I should us finest grained sandpaper to sand off the filled areas, somewhat like "buffing" it. Finally, I should spray paint, and use hard-rubber to buff it to shine. Apparently, this process has worked well for him. Although the car on which he has worked, the finishing seems less-than-professional. His explanation was that he let the metal-paste harden, and once it did harden, he didn't have right tools to buff/sand it.

Checking with a local paint and hardware store, the guy at the counter suggested using "NC-Putty" for such filling jobs and not metal-paste/putty. NC-putty is apparently much easier to work with, and can be sanded and buffed to a very nice finish.

Looking for some sound advise from this community on the best DIY approach. Unfortunately, I'm a bit under equipped in terms of tools I have. Much of what I do would be without power-tools.

Also, I am bit unsure about the use of WD-40. Is it safe to use in such situations as mine ?

As for the small dents, can I used the same technique i.e. sand-off the paint, as much as possible from the dentend portion, followed by applying the same putty, sanding, buffing, painting and polishing ?

Comment: FYI there is a [mechanics.SE](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/) for cars

Comment: Ah, never knew that @ratchetfreak. Thanks a lot. 
Request MODS to kindly migrate this question to mechanics.SE. I shall immediately join that SE site.

Comment: Search around on that site, I believe it would be a dupe if migrated.  I had a similar problem with my car and seem to recall finding a good question/answer already on that site.